# Cropping Geo-referenced scanned maps

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, clip

So I geo-referenced a few scanned maps successfully, however when it orients the scanned map correctly, a black rectangle background appears behind the map.  This doesnt allow for me to "puzzle" together different maps because the black background lays on top of other scanned map portions.  I was wondering if there's a way to crop out that background while obviously keeping the map part intact and correctly oriented/geo-referenced.

Comment: Cropping is not the right way. You must make the black rectangles transparent with nodata, alpha channel, or mask layer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use gdal_translate to crop georeferenced images.It is available in QGIS from the raster menu/Extraction/Clipper or from the command line.